# Google Charts API - how to pass it JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to receive JSON data from a web page and display it to a graph from google charts api. I want the graph to be live, and add data as it goes along. Please can you help point me in the right direction from this stage as my chart won't even show.

```
    {% block body %}

<html>
<body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {

    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

    function drawChart() {
      $.getJSON({
        url: 'removed',
        type: 'get',
        success: function (json) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var jsondata2 = $.parseJSON(json);
            //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable($.parseJSON(json));
            data.addColumn('string', 'Date Time');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
            data.addRows([
                [jsondata2.datetime, jsondata2.temperature]
            ]);
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data);
        }
      });

      var options = {
          title: 'Temperature Data',
          curveType: 'none',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

    }

    },
        packages: ['corechart']
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

This code collects the JSON object:

{'temperature': 11.0, 'datetime': '12-12-12 23-23-23'}

from a webpage I made. The network tab in developer options on my browser says it is receiving the data from that webpage. How ever, the google chart is not showing, what is wrong with it?

All help appreciated, many thanks.

```
{% block body %}

    {{tempdata}}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, make sure the json you are receiving uses double quotes,
instead of single quotes as posted in the question...

```
{"temperature": 11.0, "datetime": "12-12-12 23-23-23"}
```

next, if you want to continue to add data to the chart,
need to save a reference to the chart and data table,
before loading the data the first time, instead of creating new everytime
otherwise, you'll be drawing only the last point received each time

recommend the following setup...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Temperature');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var options = {
      title: 'Temperature Data',
      curveType: 'none',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

    function drawChart() {
      $.getJSON({
        url: 'output.txt',
        type: 'get'
      }).done(function (jsonData) {
        data.addRows([
          [jsonData.datetime, jsonData.temperature]
        ]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      });
    }
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, thanks for your answer. Regarding the JSON. When ever I call it with &.getJSON I check the network tab in my browser to see the data being retrieved it returns this ...which is in some weird html encoding:  {&#39;temperature&#39;: 11.0, &#39;datetime&#39;: &#39;12-12-12 23-23-23&#39;}

Comment: The url has a webpage with this in the body tags: {'temperature': 11.0, 'datetime': '12-12-12 23-23-23'}    I used flask and python and just returned this through a python variable on the web page

Comment: Just edited the question for you. It's using weird block and endblock tags I have no idea what they are used for, just that they might be necessary for flask?

Comment: It didnt add for some reason, it's on there now.

Comment: just did and same result. This is really weird why this isn't working... {&#39;temperature&#39;: 11.0, &#39;datetime&#39;: &#39;12-12-12 23-23-23&#39;} thats the same data coming through with these weird &# characters

Comment: Is it because the data is still in single quotes ' ' rather than " " I am not sure how to change that as I am doing it in a python dictionary as so: ` datalist = {}
 data = temperaturelog.query.order_by(temperaturelog.TemperatureID.desc()).first()
 data = data.Temperature
 datalist["temperature"] = data
 datalist["datetime"] = "12-12-12 23-23-23"`

Comment: Also when I inspect element the html and body tags are still there. Could it be to do with flask making the page or something?

Answer (score 0):

Why your chart_div is between the html and head tags?

```
<html>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<head>
```

Should be between the body tags along with the script

```
<body>
   <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
   <div id="chart_div"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       google.charts.load('current', { .... 
           // change the order
            data.addRows([
                [jsondata2.datetime, jsondata2.temperature]
            ]);
           .....
    </script>
<body>
```

Comment: I made your suggestions and it's still not changing. Following your suggestions I changed the two <head> tags to <body> and put <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div> in as your other code didnt work. It's still not working...

Comment: I edited the answer, the order was wrong. https://plnkr.co/edit/9ycYe4xgd8Yrv7oZBDe8?p=preview

Comment: Hi jonhid appreciate the help. I changed it to this just like yours and it still doesnt work: https://plnkr.co/edit/HPAeE8QON3QJIBcNtUuA?p=preview

Comment: Is there an issue with my collection of JSON data? i'm really new to this all so it could be an issue!

Comment: you must inform an url

Comment: Define "l it doesnt work ", in my  plunker with  the json hardcoded it works. It must be a problem with the webservice from where you get the data

Comment: If you json object its like this {'temperature': 11.0, 'datetime': '12-12-12 23-23-23'} you dont need to parse it.   (var jsondata2 = $.parseJSON(json);)

Comment: It doesn't work meaning the graph isn't loading, I have a blank web page. var jsondata2 = $.parseJSON(json); do you think this line is the problem? is is syntactically wrong?

Comment: What is the value of "json" ??

Comment: No idea its in the functions parameters so I thought it was my json data???

Comment: print the json object and see what you have, must be an object like {'temperature': 11.0, 'datetime': '12-12-12 23-23-23'}

Comment: to be honest with you im not sure how to print it, i tried console.log(json) checked the console but no log so im just confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166494/discussion-between-montymagic9-and-jonhid).